# Работа в терминале PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Пожалуйста, работаю в PyCharm и у меня курсор выходит черным прямоугольником (как на картинке видно), нажимал <kbd>Insert</kbd>, на мгновение помогает потом снова прямоугольник в инете ответа не нашел.

[image: скрин экрана с прямоугольным курсором]

Answer (score 0):

**File → Settings... → Editor → General → Appearance → Use block carret**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас там вероятно галочка... Удалите ее.

Comment: попробывал так сделать, но галочка уже была удаленна изначально... не помогло таким способом @MarianD

Comment: Попробуйте нажать на клавишу **Insert** не физической клавиатуре, а мышей на софтверной.

Comment: большое спасибо вам за то, что откликнулись, написал в тех поддержку джетбрайнс, они подсказали, надо было просто vim плагин отключить

Comment: @КириллМаликов, напишите это, пожалуйста,  как ответ — может быть, он будет полезным для других участников (и вы можете получить баллы за него, например от меня;-))

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в настройках vim плагин отключить

Comment: @MarianD готово)